# Как получить url страницы - chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, extension

Здраствуйте , пишу расширения для Chrome и у меня возник вопрос , как получить только url страницы

```js
//сейчас открыт например сайт - https://text-pesni.com/pesnya/pokazat/565701385/ayyo/tekst-perevod-pesni-ne-zamechala/

chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
            console.log(tabs[0].url); //выводит весть url - https://text-pesni.com/pesnya/pokazat/565701385/ayyo/tekst-perevod-pesni-ne-zamechala/ 
// а мне надо только - https://text-pesni.com/ , как мне быть ? 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо поставить location.href
Или location.pathname
их можно посмотреть в консольлоге:

```
console.log(location.href);
console.log(location.host);
//или
console.log(location.hostname);
//pathname -выведет страницу.
```